# Folders mess up after import project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a JAVA project contains multiple folders, and after I imported them into Eclipse, the folders messed up like below.

[image: project folders]

How can I put these "src/main/java" folders under the "src" one in eclipse, these folders are well-organized on my file system.

Comment: What process did you use to import the projects?

Comment: switch to `navigator` view

Comment: @Jigar Joshi, post your comment as an answer describing the difference between the two views, to make it acceptable and voteable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eclipse detects project type and it adds directory structure in `.classpath` and `.project` when you import new project,

if you want to see raw structure, switch to `navigator` view

```
windows > show view > navigator
```